# Xamarin.Forms : Error CS1704 An assembly with the same simple name 'ReactiveUI' has already been imported. Try removing one of the references

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

> *Error CS1704 An assembly with the same simple name 'ReactiveUI' has already been imported. Try removing one of the references (e.g.
>   'C:\Users\LOGESH
>   PALANI.nuget\packages\reactiveui-core\7.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\ReactiveUI.dll')
>   or sign them to enable side-by-side. GetMobileNumber.Android
>   C:\Users\LOGESH
>   PALANI\source\repos\GetMobileNumber\GetMobileNumber\GetMobileNumber.Android\CSC"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like I can't read today!
The project had a reference to the Interop and a COM reference that generated the "same" interop. So there were two and I just didn't search very well. I still don't understand why it worked in other places but this did fix it.